# Could not download aapt2-windows.jar (com.android.tools.build:aapt2:3.4.2-5326820): No cached version available for offline mode

Tags: java, android, android-studio, compiler-errors

When I run the Android project I am getting following error. Can someone please give me a solution for this problem>

```
Could not download aapt2-windows.jar (com.android.tools.build:aapt2:3.4.2-5326820): No cached version available for offline mode
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are on [offline mode](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/optimize-your-build#offline_mode). Thus to continue you must turn it off:

- Go to File > Settings (on Mac, Android Studio > Preferences)
- Click Build, Execution, Deployment > Gradle
- Uncheck the Offline work checkbox
- Click Apply or OK

Now you should be able to run your project.

Comment: @MadhurshananThillainathan Glad I could help! Please remember to accept my answer! (https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 0):

this worked to me on **Windows** :
go to **View**>**Tool Windows**>**Gradel** 
{and in the Gradel bar click on (Toogel Offline Mode)}